IServiceCollection does not contain definition for AddIdentity
In my extension method, I'm trying to add Identity services:
using Domain.Entities;
using Infrastructure.Persistence;
using Infrastructure.Seeders;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Infrastructure.Extensions;

/// <summary>
/// Provides extension methods for registering infrastructure services.
/// </summary>
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        #region DB Connection
        string? connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DummyDbName");
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
        #endregion

        #region Register Services
        services.AddScoped<IRoleSeeder, RoleSeeder>();
        #endregion

        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    }
}

When I try to do this I'm getting the error I've mentiond in the title.
I saw a few questions related to this here, but most of them recommended to install the:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

package, which is deprecated (I'm guessing its already part of something else).
Strange thing is that in my Program.cs class I can use the AddIdentity method without any issues.
Program.cs:
using Infrastructure.Extensions;
using Infrastructure.Seeders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    #region Service Collection Extensions
    builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
    #endregion

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    //builder.Services.AddIdentity This would work.
}

var app = builder.Build();
{
    // Create Scope, run seeders
    var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var roleSeeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRoleSeeder>();
    await roleSeeder.SeedRolesAsync();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
}

Infrastructure Csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Startup project csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0 is deprecated, true. You need to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore instead. Namespace stays the same
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

And change method invokation to
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore is already installed in the Infrastructure calss library, I'll update the question with the csproj

@Jez updated the answer, looks like method signature is slightly different

Core is different to AddIdentity, Core only adds user management.
I could probably configure AddIdentityCore to do the same as AddIdentity, but I don't get why I can call AddIdentity in the Program.cs and not in the extension method.

whats your csproj for the startup project?

I edited the post with the startup project's csproj.

I might have found a solution by adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI to my Infrastructure class library (even tough ist not gonna use any Razor) it lets me use AddIdentity now.
